# How to change TabIndex of TabbedPage when pushing it from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am pushing `TabbedPage` to `MasterDetailPage` from `ViewModel` by default `TabbedPage` showing first tab selected. How can  select second tab?

This is my code in ViewModel

```
async Task MoviesTab()
{
    await (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
    //var pages=new HomePage().Children.GetEnumerator();
    //pages.MoveNext();
    //new HomePage().TabIndex = 1; //Not working
}
```

`HomePage` has two tab defined in xaml

```
public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
```

When ever calling `MoviesTab()` method from side menu always appearing first tab selected.

**Edit**

The first scenario is not working & second throwing `NullReferenceExeption` exeption

Scenario 1

```
var tabbedPaged = new TabbedPage();
tabbedPaged.TabIndex = 1;
await (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
```

Scenario 2

```
await (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
((App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail as TabbedPage).TabIndex = 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Save the `TabbedPage` to a local variable and change the tab index before showing it:

```
var tabbedPaged = new TabbedPage();
tabbedPaged.TabIndex = 1;
await (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPaged);
```

Or get the current Detail page after you have pushed it as the current Detail, cast it as a TabbedPage and then set the index:

```
((App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail as TabbedPage).TabIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Above both scenarios not working for me. Please check my Edit for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `TabIndex` does nothing.

This is how I navigate:

```
tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == "Page Title");
```

Optional explanation:

If your tabbed page is inside a NavigationPage and is the first page, you can access your TabbedPage like this:

```
var tabbedPage = (App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).RootPage as TabbedPage;
```

Page title is set in the ContentPage, to which you want to navigate to.

Comment: This is the correct answer: tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[1]